# asp.net header forwarding not working for external Identity provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I use asp.net Identity with AzureAD as an external Identity provider in my Balzor server side app. In development environment (localhost) logging in works fine. When I deploy the app to an on premise server in a docker image behind Nginx, it does not. Microsoft sends the error message `AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application`. I have added the proper reply URL to Azure portal. As far as I can tell, the request uses `http`, while `https` should be used, which causes the error.

Since Nginx handles secure transport, the headers need to be forwarded, so I configured Nginx and enabled Header forwarding in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
                options.ForwardLimit = 1;
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("123.xxx.xxx.xxx"));
            });
```

and at the very beginning of `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

app.UseHsts();

// should not be necessary but I tried with and without
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

When I enable [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#troubleshoot), I think I see that the correct header is forwarded from Nginx:

```
...
Header: X-Forwarded-For: 123.xxx.xxx.xxx
Header: X-Forwarded-Proto: https
...
```

To me it looks like `ChallengeResult()` in `ExternalLogin.Post` is not using the forwarded headers and sends `http://my.domain.ch/signin-oidc` instead of `https://` as reply URL, which causes the error.

I ran out of ideas what else I could try, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found the mistake: I did add the wrong proxy IP. Since my asp.net app is hosted on docker, I had to add the IP address of the docker image as proxy, not the IP of the server which hosts nginx and docker. In fact, I added the default network used by docker

```
options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.17.0.0"), 16));
```